# SQL to select different records from a table based on different cases

Tags: sql, database

A table has data for trade deals. A trade deal (identified by deal_no) may have multiple records in the table.  However I want to select only one record. The condition to select one record depends on different cases.

From the attached figure, I need to select the record with latest step_release_date, which is calculated as per below condition:

```
CASE
WHEN (DEALSTP.IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE > 0 ) THEN (DEALSTP.IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE)
WHEN (DEALSTP.IXSTP_REL_DATE_A > 0 ) THEN (DEALSTP.IXSTP_REL_DATE_A) 
ELSE (DEALSTP.IXSTP_REL_DATE_B) 
END ) as Step_release_date
```

How can I select the latest step_release_date from this table ?

[image]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You should tag with the database you are really using.  If you give your questions appropriate tags, then you are more likely to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `GREATEST` here:

```
SELECT
    GREATEST(IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE, IXSTP_REL_DATE_A, IXSTP_REL_DATE_B) AS Step_release_date
FROM DEALSTP;
```

If you want to use `CASE` expressions, this can also be done, with a bit more work:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE > IXSTP_REL_DATE_A AND
              IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE > IXSTP_REL_DATE_B
         THEN IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE
         ELSE CASE WHEN IXSTP_REL_DATE_A > IXSTP_REL_DATE_B
                   THEN IXSTP_REL_DATE_A
                   ELSE IXSTP_REL_DATE_B END AS Step_release_date
FROM DEALSTP;
```

Comment: The record where I get IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE as greater than 0 needs to be considered. If theres no such record, then I need to check the second column i.e. IXSTP_REL_DATE_A for any record having value greater than 0. If that too doesnt yield any value, then I need to check the third column i.e. IXSTP_REL_DATE_B. If in any of these columns, I get more than one record, I need to select the one with latest date value

Comment: @user3532090 But I think in all cases taking the greatest column supports your logic.  If only one column is non zero, and the other two zero, then you still want the greatest.

Comment: Using greatest can give me a value from the third column for a record. While the requirement is to first choose from 1st column. Only if I dont get a value from that column, I am supposed to check the next column

Comment: Did you actually try my query against your data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and appropriate `limit` functionality.  This would look like:

```
select t.*,
       (CASE WHEN DEALSTP.IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE > 0
             THEN DEALSTP.IXSTP_OFFERING_DATE
             WHEN DEALSTP.IXSTP_REL_DATE_A > 0
             THEN DEALSTP.IXSTP_REL_DATE_A 
             ELSE DEALSTP.IXSTP_REL_DATE_B)
        END) as Step_release_date
from t
order by Step_release_date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that `fetch first` (although standard) is not supported by all databases, but all databases should have similar functionality.